# What are the tools required to learn in order to create atari 2600 Games

Tags: assembly

I am a beginner in C++ and i would like to learn how to  create a clone of an Atari 2600 game and using an emulator allow it to run on my current PC. my question is what programming language do i need to know in order to get started, i am aware assembly maybe required but i do not have any background in assembly. so if someone could give me a briefing on the process or point me to the starting point i would appreciate it greatly. i apologize upfront if the question is not constructive.

Comment: A quick Google search turned up a few things, notably: http://atariage.com/2600/programming/.

Comment: This doesn't really seem off-topic to me, given that it is a specific question about how the heck to make an Atari 2600 game these days. There was even an extremely useful specific answer.

Comment: You will need to learn 6502 assembly language, beyond that everything else is subjective. Fortunately, 6502 and Motorola 68K are surprisingly similar, so if you have experience with the more common 68K you should not be completely lost.

Comment: Speak of the devil, that is all explained in the link in the first comment :P That really ought to be expanded into an answer, perhaps a community answer. This is a valid question if you replace "to learn" with "for use".

Comment: This is still about "what tool should I use to get started" which covers two close reasons. Being about an old computer (as cool as the 2600 [undoubtedly was](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucRYLobga0g)) doesn't really grant it immunity from the rules. This question would work if it presented a more specific problem.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman If you feel as though it can be edited to fit the community please do so.